# Prove that at least one of these value is non-negative

Tags: contest-math, real-numbers

Given real numbers

${a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6,a_7,a_8}$

Prove that at least one of these value is non-negative

${a_1a_3+a_2a_4}$ , ${a_1a_5+a_2a_6}$ , ${a_1a_7+a_2a_8,}$
${a_3a_5+a_4a_6}$ , ${a_3a_7+a_4a_8}$ , ${a_5a_7+a_6a_8}$

I’ve tried to solve by contradiction but I really have no idea how to start.

Comment: Hint: Think of them as dot products among the 2D vectors $(a_1,a_2), (a_3,a_4), (a_5, a_6), (a_7, a_8)$.

Comment: Thanks for hint.I finally did it

Answer (score 1):

By pigeon hole we can prove that there is at least 1 pair of these vectors which angle between them is less than or equal 90 degrees ,hence their dot product is non-negative.